# Windows Phone 8 sdk how to get installed application list

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I am quite new to windows app development. Is there any way I can find all apps installed on a device?

I searched on google but so far I didnt have any success.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a way to obtain a list of installed applications.